# Rotated div offset top position from based on left position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, physics

I am struggling to find offset top position from left.
For example left 50px i want find top position based on left.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure euclidean geometry problem, but you currently can't calculate this offset. You need **one** of these data:

- the rotation angle
- the distance between the (left-)end of the line and your point

I guess you know the rotation, so we'll use this value. Let's say you've made a 30° rotation, we've got this:

[image]

Using Pythagore's theorem, we've got:

```
    tan(30) = H / 50px
<=> H = tan(30) * 50px
<=> H = 28.867px
```

So, take your angle (ɑ), and apply this formula:

> H = tan(ɑ) * 50px

In Javascript:

```
var offset = {
    x: 50,
    y: null
}
var alpha = 30;
offset.y = Math.tan(alpha * (180 / Math.PI)) * offset.x;

console.log(offset);
```

Comment: Does these lines are enough for you?

Comment: In  the above formula we are not given any input of line top and bottom positions of rotated div then how we can calculate top relative to rotated div

Comment: I don't understand your comment at all.Please make your question clearer, and add a small code sample.

Comment: I understand your provided solution and worked for me. Thanks :-)